# EF LINQ translation: complex query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have this code (Note **l.FirstOrDefault().Name**):

```
    var qry = from peron in db.Persons
    join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
    join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
    select new {peron.Fio, room.Name, passport.Number, Count = 0};
    qry = qry.GroupBy(l => new {l.Fio, l.Number})
          .Select(l => new {
                               l.Key.Fio, 
                               l.FirstOrDefault().Name, 
                               l.Key.Number, 
                               Count = l.Count()
                            });
```

This translates to this:

```
SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Project4].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
        [Project4].[C1] AS [C2], 
        [Project4].[Number] AS [Number], 
        [Project4].[C2] AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project3].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
            [Project3].[Number] AS [Number], 
            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent6]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[Passport_Id] = [Extent7].[Id]
                WHERE ([Extent6].[Room_Id] IS NOT NULL) AND (([Project3].[Fio] = [Extent6].[Fio]) OR (([Project3].[Fio] IS NULL) AND ([Extent6].[Fio] IS NULL))) AND (([Project3].[Number] = [Extent7].[Number]) OR (([Project3].[Number] IS NULL) AND ([Extent7].[Number] IS NULL)))) AS [C2]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Distinct1].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
                [Distinct1].[Number] AS [Number], 
                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name]
                    FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent3]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rooms] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Room_Id] = [Extent4].[Id]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[Passport_Id] = [Extent5].[Id]
                    WHERE (([Distinct1].[Fio] = [Extent3].[Fio]) OR (([Distinct1].[Fio] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[Fio] IS NULL))) AND (([Distinct1].[Number] = [Extent5].[Number]) OR (([Distinct1].[Number] IS NULL) AND ([Extent5].[Number] IS NULL)))) AS [C1]
                FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                    [Extent1].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
                    [Extent2].[Number] AS [Number]
                    FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Passport_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
                    WHERE [Extent1].[Room_Id] IS NOT NULL
                )  AS [Distinct1]
            )  AS [Project3]
        )  AS [Project4]
```

It's very complex query... However if I replace l.FirstOrDefault().Name to Name = "", I get simple query

```
var qry = from peron in db.Persons
    join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
    join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
    select new {peron.Fio, room.Name, passport.Number, Count = 0};
qry = qry.GroupBy(l => new {l.Fio, l.Number}).Select(l => new {l.Key.Fio, Name = "", l.Key.Number, Count = l.Count()});    

SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Fio], 
        N'' AS [C2], 
        [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [Number], 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Fio] AS [K1], 
            [Extent2].[Number] AS [K2], 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Passport_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Room_Id] IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY [Extent1].[Fio], [Extent2].[Number]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

I also get simple query if I add room.Name to grouped fields and use by this way

```
var qry = from peron in db.Persons
                    join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
                    join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
                    select new {peron.Fio, room.Name, passport.Number, Count = 0};
                qry = qry.GroupBy(l => new {l.Fio, l.Name, l.Number})
                      .Select(l => new 
                      {
                          l.Key.Fio, 
                          l.Key.Name, 
                          l.Key.Number, 
                          Count = l.Count()
                      });
```

How I can fix the issue with **l.FirstOrDefault().Name**?
Thanks.

Comment: Skip using Entity-framework and use raw sql with a light weight object mapper like Dapper. That query is just insane.

Comment: I don't need workarounds. I would like to use EF.

Comment: EF generates SQL. Why not write the SQL directly instead. You can still mapp it to EF entities.

Comment: @magnus 'i dont like your tools' isnt a terribly helpful comment

Comment: @LukeMcGregor EF has support for mapping raw SQL to entities for complex situations like this. Why not use it.

Comment: @Magnus I would like to avoid hardcode, if it possible.

Comment: @magnus, thats not the question the OP asked. But I would suggest that the mapping EF has done here is not unreasonable based on the query. Handcoding with EF should only be used where you need to for performance reasons IMO.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor No it should have been an outer apply top 1 sub query.

Comment: Try using [LINQ DefaultIfEmpty outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) or use the `let` keyword to extract the name outside the `new` block.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I agree with you

Comment: @pasty could you please provide an example? I recently started work with EF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not ordering the group I assume you just want any of the names from the group. You can use an aggregate like `Max` than (Yes it works even on strings). I believe that will generate a more reasonable query.

```
new {
       l.Key.Fio, 
       Name = l.Max(x => x.Name), 
       l.Key.Number, 
       Count = l.Count()
    });
```

Comment: Nice duct tape xD
Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help @Serg046